# best way to map traffic in google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

so have a a bunch of google cloud compute instances, each instance has a unique internal and external ip address.

what's the best way to create a traffic mapping system in google cloud platform to map traffics like this:

a.foobar.example.com go to compute instance a.

b.foobar.example.com go to compute instance b.

c.foobar.example.com go to compute instance c.

My first thought is create a wild card record in my DNS server
like this:

*.foobar.example.com points to xx.xx.xx.xx

(an ip address of a google mapping service like a load balancer, and then google mapping service takes the request and forward the traffic to a particular instance based on url pattern.)

Tried google load balancer, however it doesn't really give me ability to map to an ip address, it only gives ability to map to a backend service, which needs an instance group.

any insights are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, your best approach is using DNS records rather than the LB. The records should be explicitly added like this and using A records.

```
a.foobar.example.com A xx.xx.xx.xx (Public IP of instance A)
.
.
c.foobar.example.com A xx.xx.xx.xx (Public IP of instance C)
```

Another approach I can think of is using another VM where you can install NGINX and set it as a reverse proxy. Then you can even map to the VM's using their internal IPs, for example:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name a.foobar.example.com;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://INTERNAL_IP_SERVER_A:80;
        }
}

server {
    listen      80;
    server_name b.foobar.example.com;
    location / {
                proxy_pass http://INTERNAL_IP_SERVER_B:80;
        }
}

#And so on
```